# Mapping generic properties with reflection / Cast property to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, mapping

I'm using reflection to map (set properties) on one class (xSearchObject) from a DTO (xSearchQuery). I've tried to reduce the code down to make it easier to see what I'm trying to achieve. I can't change `SearchField`, but I can change `DTOSearchField`.

- Source Class has *n* properties of type `DTOSearchField<T>`.
- Destination Class has *n* properties of type `SearchField<T>`.
- Source and Destination have the same number of properties with the
  same names.

**Source Class Property Type**

```
public class DTOSearchField<T> : IDTOSearchField
{
  public T EqualTo;
}
```

**Destination class Property Type:**

```
public class SearchField<T> : ISearchField
{
  public void WhereEquals(T value)
  {
    _clauses.Add(_name + " = " + Converter.ConvertValueToSql(value));
  }
    
  // etc
}
```

**Mapping:** (Based on [Lightweight Object to Object Mapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29118/Lightweight-Object-to-Object-Mapper))
I can do the mapping quite happily if instead of a generic `DTOSearchField<T>` I have, for example, `StringDTOSearchField`, `IntDTOSearchField` etc classes and cast to those. So for each source property:

```
if (sourceVal.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(StringDTOSearchField)))
{
  var destinationProperty = destinationPropertyAccessor.GetPropertyValue(destination, propertyMatch.DestinationProperty.Name) as SearchField<string>;

  var sourceStringField = sourceVal as StringSearchField;
  if (sourceStringField != null)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceStringField.EqualTo)) destinationProperty.WhereEquals(sourceStringField.EqualTo);
  }
}
else if (sourceVal.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IntDTOSearchField)))
{
  // Etc
}
```

Or i could keep the generic `DTOSearchField<T>` and do a load of If-Then-elses based on:

```
Type t = sourceVal.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

to cast to an appropriate type,

But I feel like I should be able to do something like:

```
Type t = sourceVal.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
var destinationProperty = destinationPropertyAccessor.GetPropertyValue(destination, propertyMatch.DestinationProperty.Name) as SearchField<t>;
destinationProperty.WhereEquals(sourceVal.EqualTo.Value);
```

Since `sourceVal` is a `DTOSearchField<T>` and `destinationProperty` is a `SearchField<T>`, and they both have properties of type T it feels like it shouldn't matter if you don't know what T is until runtime.

I understand the cast won't work as T isn't known until runtime. Is there anyway to achieve what I want, other than If-Then-Else for every possible type? It seems to defeat the advantages of using generics if I have to do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could just call the method WhereEquals through reflection, but I would recommend leveraging the generics to your advantage as follows (since you have access to change DTOSearchField):

```cs
public interface IDTOSearchField
{
    void MapToSearchField(ISearchField searchField);
}

public class DTOSearchField<T> : IDTOSearchField
{
    public T EqualTo;

    public void MapToSearchField(ISearchField searchField)
    {
        if (!(searchField is SearchField<T>))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("SearchField must be of type " + typeof(T).FullName + ".", "searchField");
        }

        ((SearchField<T>)searchField).WhereEquals(EqualTo);
    }
}
```

You can then use this new method on the interface to map as follows:

```cs
    public void MapField(IDTOSearchField source, ISearchField destination)
    {
        source.MapToSearchField(destination);
    }
```

If you don't want to make the DTOSearchField class have knowledge of the SearchField class, there are ways around this, but that is too much of a discussion for this answer.